# Bootstrap 4.3.1 columns reordering class="order-md-1"

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design, multiple-columns

Slowly losing my plot trying to reorder columns on stacking. Having read articles, I'm working my way up starting with smaller devices. So I got the columns stack the way I need there. But on bigger screens I struggle to arrange it differently. I tried nested rows and order-md- classes. Where am I going wrong?
The visual order I need on desktop (which doesn't work): 
first row A | C then on the second row
 B | D
On smaller screen (which does work) these must stack as follows:
A
D
B
C
Here's my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="loadingBar()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">A</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-4">D</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">B</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-3">C</div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be working as you describe. A D B C on small, A B | C D on md and larger screens

Comment: The order I need on md and larger screens is row 1: [A C] row 2:  [B D] :/

Comment: Change B to order-md-3 and C to order-md-2

Comment: Oh my! Bootstrap counts columns horizontally from left to right! Thanks for the revelation lol and for dragging me out of this misery! I might be pushing my luck, but is there a way to make my oddly heighted divs stick to each other vertically instead of short divs taking up the height of the tallest in its row and leaving unsightly gaps. Floating didn't work.

Comment: For clarity, if you have another question please create a new one and we’d be happy to help!